# How to use Greek symbols in the lstlisting environment?

Tags: listings

If I put `∆` in `lstlisting` it converts it into space. How to avoid that? I need to write this code in `lstlisting`:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    \multiput(x,y)(∆x,∆y){n}{object}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: You need to literate it. See the manual for more information. Just an untested try: `\lstset{literate={∆}{{\tiny$\Delta$}}1}`.

Comment: You're the man!

Comment: @TeXnician sounds like an answer to me

Answer (score 2):

`lstlisting`'s output routine will need to know how to parse unicode input. So you need to provide those information. The right setting for that is `literate`. The common syntax is `literate={<input>}{{<output>}}<number of characters>`.

That means to literate your input delta you need to use something like `\lstset{literate={∆}{{\tiny$\Delta$}}1}`. Please note that using this output version might not look very pleasing to you. Maybe you want to use a different representation than a down-scaled capital delta, but you get the idea.